# Passing an answer to choices in InquirerJS?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, inquirerjs

How would I be able to get an answer from a previous question and pass on to the next question for choices for inquirerJS? I know the fact that it is asynchronous but i'm not sure how to create promises here. Any further insight and help would be great.

Example:

```
var questions = [{
    name: 'menu',
    type: 'checkbox',
    message: 'Which food do you like eating?',
    choices: ['pizza', 'hotdog', 'hamburger', 'sandwiches'],
   }, {
    name: 'favorite',
    type: 'checkbox',
    message: 'Which one do you like most?',
    choices: answers.menu,   <------- doesn't work because it is asynchronous
   };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation `choises` can be a function.

```
var inquirer = require('inquirer');

var questions = [
  {
    name: 'menu',
    type: 'checkbox',
    message: 'Which food do you like eating?',
    choices: ['pizza', 'hotdog', 'hamburger', 'sandwiches'],
  },
  {
    name: 'favorite',
    type: 'checkbox',
    message: 'Which one do you like most?',
    choices: (answers) => {
        return answers.menu;
    }
  },
];

inquirer.prompt(questions).then(answers => {
  console.log(answers);
});
```